# Automatic Login with PHP + cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to log in with cURL and PHP on a huawei router (HG150-U), I have the credentials.
Apparently, when you log in from the browser, 3 cookies are created.
Two of which are the username and password of the login, but the third has the name of SESSIONID, and for more that I have searched, I can not find where it is generated.

Note: It seems that cookie is generated at the time of sending the request.

The query looks like this
[image: Screenshot of the query]

Comment: It stores the password... in a cookie... in plain text? *sigh*

Comment: I have this code and it works:
.

$ch = curl_init(); $url = "190.214.78.190/cgi-bin/home_wireless.asp"; 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "SESSIONID=6cb6816c; uid=usuario; psw=usuario");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');

$data = curl_exec($ch);

///But to discover what the SESSION ID is, I have to use a browser to login and copy it.

Comment: @RonaldNavarrete [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session ID is not predictable, that's the point. (Well, it's not *supposed* to be, but it is suspiciously short.) So, don't create the cookies yourself. Instead, set a CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR in your curl options, pointing it to a temp file, then hit the login page by passing the user/pass and it will create the cookies in your jar file. Then make a second curl request to the data page you want, now using that file in CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, and curl will pass along the cookies that were created from the last hit and stored in the jar. Something like this:

```
// Send user/password to the login page so that we get new cookies.
$curl = curl_init('<whatever the login page url is>');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookies'); // cookies get stored in this file
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    '<username field>' => '<username>',
    '<password field>' => '<password>',
]);
curl_setopt(...);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// Send the cookies we just saved to the data page you want
$curl = curl_init('<whatever the data page url is>');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookies'); // cookies in this file get sent
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt(...);
$page = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: I still can not log in. It keeps redirecting me to login.

Comment: Are the cookies saved correctly in the cookie file?

Comment: I didn't save them in any file, that was my mistake.

Answer (score -1):

First rule of the internet: passwords should be hashed. And they shouldn't be stored in cookies.

If your database gets hacked, then all the passwords are right there for everyone to see.

What you want to do is hash these passwords. There are lots of "one way" hashing algorithms that will hash the password to the state where you can't decrypt it (unless you want to brute force it for years on end)

PHP has a function, `password_hash()`, that uses the BCrypt hashing algorithm and will keep these passwords safe.

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Also, don't store any user information in cookies unless you're making a session ID auth system. Store that kind of stuff in a session.

https://www.w3schools.com/pHp/php_sessions.asp

Good luck!

Comment: I think you misunderstood OP's situation. They haven't written the code that creates the cookies, that's coming from the router. They're asking how to login via script instead of via browser.

Comment: Encrypted isn't the correct terminology here, you mean hashed. Hashing and encrypting are different things.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I'll edit the post. @Marty